# Add info windows to line [google map]

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

this my code.it shows my coordinates as line. i want to add info window this line..
when i click this line it show any info which i want.

P.S. Sorry for my English :(

```
flightPlanCoordinates = [
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9921196514,47.8604733650 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9922511293,47.8606186245 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9926358563,47.8611079146 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9929381070,47.8615028229 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng( 40.9931715315,47.8620863814 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng( 40.9933869955,47.8623375976 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9936024589,47.8625888155 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9942600516, 47.8634730879 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9946698905, 47.8639284456),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9951427577,47.8643998201 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9956477404 ,47.8648835770),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9959645185, 47.8651699964),
                 new google.maps.LatLng( 40.9962812958, 47.8654564186 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng( 40.9965401588,47.8657069220 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng( 40.9970324883 ,47.8661781983),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9972659548, 47.8663989707 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9975468767, 47.8664409273),
                 new google.maps.LatLng( 40.9978740427,47.8662277913 ),
                new google.maps.LatLng( 40.9982012084,47.8660150777 ),
                    new google.maps.LatLng( 40.9985497469,47.8658461824),
 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9988327045,47.8660951747),
  new google.maps.LatLng(40.9991045183,47.8664072712),              
   new google.maps.LatLng(40.9992585926,47.8665868156),                 





        ];
        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: flightPlanCoordinates,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2
        });

        flightPath.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Your code makes no attempt at creating an InfoWindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a ["click" listener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapsEventListener) to the polyline that opens the [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) and displays the content. Something like this (not tested):

```
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var contentString ="content for infowindow";
  google.maps.event.addListener(flightPlan,'click', function(event) {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map);
  });
```

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GenericMapBrowser.asp?filename=I5Polyline.xml)